# How to print block before each group of 5 numbers without adding a new variable?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I am stuck in a program where I have to print "Block" before every 5 numbers without using an additional variable.
This is the code:

```
for index,i in enumerate(range(1,11)):
 print(i)
```

expected output:

```
Block
1
2
3
4
5
Block
6
7
8
9
10
```

Please help new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `x % 5` will give you zero if and only if `x` is a multiple of five.

So, if you wanted to output "Block" before `1, 6, 11, ...`, you could use:

```
if (i - 1) % 5 == 0: print('Block')
```

before printing the number.

In other words, it's as simple as:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    if (i - 1) % 5 == 0: print('Block')
    print(i)
```

Running that program gives your expected output of:

```
Block
1
2
3
4
5
Block
6
7
8
9
10
```

Note that this will only work if you start at one (as it appears you do). Any other start point will require a slightly modified solution.

Comment: Can it be more clear? it shows error do something not defined

Comment: @Dhruv: sorry, `doSomething()` was just a placeholder where you needed to do something. The "something" *you* need to do is `print("Block")`. I'll make that clearer.

Comment: Actually its a requirement of writing a "block" after 5 numbers

Comment: @Dhruv, have modified your question and this answer to take that into account.

Comment: it do prints block after 5 and 10 like "block5block10block" but it does not print in expected output: "12345block678910bloc"

Comment: @Dhruv, just tested the code I posted and it *does* print your expected output (see addition to answer). Suggest you compare that code with whatever *you're* running, there's a better than average chance you've made a transcription error.

Comment: hi I am sorry the output which is required by him is as edited a minor change. So sorry

Answer (score 0):

In python this can be done by

```
For index,I in enumerate (range(1,21)):
     Print(i)
     if(i%5==0):
         Print("block")
```